# PowerShell Script Not Working As Intended When Getting AD Groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am working on a PowerShell script with a menu to select different ways to search info in Active Directory. The command with Get-ADUser works correctly, but the command with Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership has an odd behavior. When I select that option (3) and enter a username and run the command nothing gets output to the display, if I then quit by using (Q) on the menu the groups then display.

```
function Show-Menu 
{ 
     param ( 
           [string]$Title = 'AD Search Tool' 
     ) 
     cls 
     Write-Host "================ $Title ================" 

     Write-Host "1: Search Users by Title" 
     Write-Host "2: Press '2' for this option." 
     Write-Host "3: List User's Groups" 
     Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit." 
} 

do 
{ 
     Show-Menu 
     $input = Read-Host "Please make a selection" 
     switch ($input) 
     { 
           '1' { 
                cls 
                $title = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Title'
                if ($title){
                    Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName, Enabled, Title, EmployeeID -Filter "(Title -eq '$title') -and (Enabled -eq 'True')" | select Enabled, EmployeeID, Name, SamAccountName, Title 
                }

           } '2' { 
                cls 
                'You chose option #2' 

           } '3' { 
                cls 
                $user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter User Name'
                if ($user){
                    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name | sort name 
                }

           } 'q' { 
                cls
                return 
           } 
     } 
     pause 
} 
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Write-Host` to write the result immediately. 
To do it through the pipe, you can use `Out-String` first.

Therefore

```
 Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name | sort name  | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

instead of

```
 Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name | sort name
```

will do the trick.
* Color is optional. I just like cyan.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much. Cyan is an ok color I guess but I'll pass. lol